# Making a menu through serial

Tags: serial

I'm working on a project for a robot and I'm trying to make a menu that can run on start up where the user can calibrate the mid-point for the servos (so they're stationary) and the ldrs so it can tell between black lines and white paper. So, I've made the menu a switch case where it calls the calibration when user enters a value, the calibration routines are their own functions.

What I want to know how to do is how to make it so when the user is finished with a calibrator it will go back to the menu function and also how to get the menu to exit on user input. So far when the menu calls a function it will just loop on it.

The menu:

```
void Menu(){

  Serial.println("|****************************|");
  Serial.println("|**|Ardnoid Configuration |**|");
  Serial.println("|**|        Menu          |**|");
  Serial.println("|****************************|");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Select one of the following options:");
  Serial.println("1 LDR configuration");
  Serial.println("2 Servo calibration");
  Serial.println("3 Exit configuration menu");

  while(!Serial.available()){}
  int i = Serial.parseInt();

  switch(i){

  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
    while(srvConOn == true){
      srvConfig();
      }
    break;strong text
  case 3:
    Serial.println("Leaving configuration menu"); 
    break;
  default:
    Serial.println("Unrecognized command, try again!");
    } 
 }
```

and the servo calibration:

```
void srvConfig(){

Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Begin servo stop calibration routine");

int x = 0;

  while(x == 0){

    Serial.println("Enter values for servos until both are stationary");
    delay(100);

    Serial.println("Enter value for left servo");
    while (!Serial.available()) {;}
    left = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(left);
    delay(100);

    Serial.println("Enter value for right servo");
    while (!Serial.available()) {;}
    right = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(right);
    delay(100);

    srvR.write(right);
    srvL.write(left);

    Serial.println("have both servos stopped?");
    Serial.println("1 = Yes | 2 = No"); 

    int j;
    while (!Serial.available()) {;}
    j = Serial.parseInt();

    if (j == 1) {
      Serial.println("Saving calibration");
      EEPROM.write(leftMid, left);
      EEPROM.write(rightMid, right);
      srvConOn == false; 
      x == 1;
      } else if (j == 2) {
        Serial.println("Try again");
        Serial.println();
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your switch/case inside an infinite loop, and return from
the `Menu()` function when the user presses '3'. E.g.:

```c++
void Menu() {
    Serial.println(menu_banner);
    for (;;) {
        switch (Serial.read()) {
            case '1': ldrConfig(); break;
            case '2': srvConfig(); break;
            case '3': return;
            default: continue;  // includes the case 'no input'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good work around for the menu! But how would you suggest getting from the functions back to the menu switch?

Comment: @ROff: This is already handled here: when `srvConfig()` returns, we `break` out of the switch, then we get into another iteration of the infinite `for (;;)` loop, then back to `switch (Serial.read())`. The infinite loop is only broken when the user types '3'.

Comment: I just ran it through and it seems like whenever I try to save the srvConfig instead of returning to the menu it will just run srvConfig again

Comment: @ROff: In `srvConfig()`, replace `x == 1` with `x = 1`, or more simply with `return` (and then get rid of `x`)..